Запит про невизначені прикметники
Добридень! Маю запит про невизначені прикметники. Чи за останні триста років ставали десь у текстах старі невизначені(нині же короткі форми) прикметники, де б вони відмінювалися, як іменники? Щось на взір:
|Зелен|
|Зелена|
|Зелену|
|Зелен|
|Зеленом|
|Зелені|
|Зелене|

Вітаємо вас у спільноті Stackexchange Ukrainian Language! Тут, у спільноті, ми намагаємося надавати якісні відповіді на запитання з української мови. Будь ласка, переформулюйте ваш запит так, щоб його можна було зрозуміти однозначно, наведіть приклади вжитку та зовнішні посилання на корисні ресурси, які ви опрацювали самостійно в пошуках відповіді на своє запитання.
